# How to create a widget for window 10 and 11 using dotnet 6

Tags: c#, .net, window, .net-6.0

I want to create a widget to show some information to users to businesses regarding information and the widget should look like as attached screenshot. It should behave like start on startup and like widget is running but there is not any property in the taskbar for it

I want to use dotnet6 for that

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are looking for a personal widget to display system info, like seen in the screenshot. Try using this program called [Rainmeter.](https://www.rainmeter.net) There are lots of documentation to help create your own Rainmeter widget too.

If you are looking to create your own widget using dotnet6 you can create a windows form application normally but add something like this `this.ShowInTaskbar = false;` in your form_Load event function as seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.load?view=windowsdesktop-6.0).

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showintaskbar?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) is some more information on that code I gave.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-csharp-winform-visual-studio?view=vs-2022) is some more information on how to create a windows form application.

To get your program to startup on computer start, place a shortcut to your program here `C:\Users\[User Name]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`
More information on this startup location [here](https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/how-to-access-the-windows-10-startup-folder/).

Comment: Thanks, it is for showing just showing some charts to business users so I have to create a small app in windows form